# Define the domain in which $f(z)=z\cdot \text{Im} (z)$ is differentiable and calculate its derivative.

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, complex-numbers

Define the domain in which the below function is differentiable and calculate its derivative:

> $$f(z)=z\cdot \text{Im} (z)$$

I tried checking the analyticity of the function by definining $z=x+iy$, I get $$f(z)=(x+iy)y$$ but by the Cauchy-Riemann equations, it is not an analytic function:
$$ \dfrac{\partial u(x,y)}{\partial x} = \dfrac{\partial(xy)}{\partial x} = y \neq \dfrac{\partial v(x,y)}{\partial y} = \dfrac{\partial (y^{2})}{y} = 2y$$
In which $$Re(f(z)) = u(x,y)$$ and $$Im(f(z)) = v(x,y)$$

Comment: Welcome. You tried what, exactly?

Comment: I tried defining z = x + iy which leads to f(x, y) = (x + iy)*y and through CR is not an analytic function

Comment: On this site it is very helpful for *everyone* if you show your working. Right now I can't help you because I can't see what you did, in particular I can't see your thought process and what, if anything, went wrong. Most users of this site feel the same way and won't answer your question until it is cleaned up. P.S. format using MathJax please!

Comment: Well if you restrict the domain to the real line $f(z)=0$ is certainly differentiable. What about $Im(z)=cst$ or $Re(z)=0$ etc.

Comment: @zwim $f$ is not complex differentiable away from the origin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your question is "What is the domain for which the first derivative of $f$ exist?," then we can revert to the definition of the derivative

$$\begin{align}
f'(z)&=\lim_{\Delta z\to 0}\frac{f(z+\Delta z)-f(z)}{\Delta z}\\\\
&=\lim_{\Delta z\to 0}\frac{(z+\Delta z)\text{Im}(z+\Delta z)-z\text{Im}(z)}{\Delta z}\\\\
&=\lim_{\Delta z\to 0}\frac{(z+\Delta z)(y+\Delta y)-zy}{\Delta z}\\\\
&=\lim_{\Delta z\to 0}\left(\frac{z\Delta y}{\Delta z}+(y+\Delta y)\right)\\\\
\end{align}$$

and answer "For which values of $z$ does the limit exist?"  And this boils down to finding the limit, $\lim_{\Delta z\to 0}\frac{z\Delta y}{\Delta z}$, if it exists.

Can you finish now?

Comment: This limit is not convergent, am I missing something?

Comment: It converges only if $z=0$.